# FuelPHP and Mustache Partials

Tags: php, mustache, partials, fuelphp

I am building a CMS using FuelPHP and want to use Mustache. I have a theme that I purchased from wrapbootstrap that includes mustaches files as a reference.

Mustache installed fine and I can get regullar mustache tags to work i.e. {{title}}

However I cannot seem to figure out how to get partials to function. I have tried changing the path to the partials and every other resource I could find on google before posting here.

```
    <html lang="en">
    {{> layout._template.header}}

    <body>
    {{> layout.topbar}}

        <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
         <script type="text/javascript">
         try{ace.settings.check('main-container' , 'fixed')}catch(e){}
         </script>
         <div class="main-container-inner">

         {{> layout.sidenav}}

            <div class="main-content">
                {{> layout.breadcrumbs}}

                <div class="page-content">
                    {{^page.no-header}}{{!if no such thing as "no-header", then print header}}
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1>{{page.title}} {{#page.description}}<small><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i> {{page.description}}</small>{{/page.description}}</h1>
                    </div><!--/.page-header-->
                    {{/page.no-header}}

                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12">
<!-- PAGE CONTENT BEGINS -->
{{> page.content }}
<!-- PAGE CONTENT ENDS -->
                     </div><!--/.col-->
                    </div><!--/.row-->

                </div><!--/.page-content-->

            </div><!--/.main-content -->

            {{> layout.settings}}
         </div><!--/.main-container-inner-->

         <a href="#" id="btn-scroll-up" class="btn-scroll-up btn btn-sm btn-inverse">
            <i class="icon-double-angle-up icon-only bigger-110"></i>
         </a>
        </div><!--/.main-container-->

        {{> layout._template.footer}}


    </body>
</html>
```

I have almost removed the . from {{> layout._template.header}} and replaced with / that I found here also but that did not work either. https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Template-Loading

Sorry if this has been answered before I am just really stumped.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a little more context? What is `{{ layout }}` in your rendering context? What value should `layout._template.header` have? How are you registering your partials?